# Fast-paced, windowed multimedia board or puzzle game for Windows 3.x, featuring the “Toasty!” sound effect

Tags: identify-this-game

There is a game I remember playing quite a while ago.

I have only the vaguest recollections of the gameplay.  It was a 2D, maybe faux-3D game, I played it with a mouse, inside a window (it was *not* full-screen); it probably even displayed multiple windows with pretty standard Windows buttons as I passed through stages.  There were sounds, lots of them, I think there might have been background music.  It may have been some kind of a board game, or a puzzle game with multiple timed rounds.  There were probably points.  I remember matching up colourful 3D shapes (as in, some platonic solids, pyramid, cube, sphere) against each other.  <s>Or maybe the shapes represented pieces on the board.  I am not sure.</s>  It <s>may have been an educational game, and</s> may have been included on a CD-ROM attached to a textbook for the computing class.  It was relatively fast-paced and rather cheesy, though I know it doesn’t really narrow it down.

There is, however, one distinct mechanic that I remember pretty clearly.  At random times, in a random corner of the window, a button would appear for a short time (up to a second or so), depicting some kind of a human figure, and [the “Toasty!” sound effect from Mortal Kombat](https://youtu.be/vb5Vlb9atEk) would be heard (at a rather low sampling rate<s>, 11 kHz or even 8 kHz</s>; I remember pretty clearly how muffled it sounded); this mechanic was probably a direct reference to that game.  I remember the figure as a kind of a sorcerer zapping a lightning <s>from his wand, or maybe</s> from his hands<s>, but in retrospect it might have even been Dan Forden himself with a fancy background</s>.  If I managed to click this button before it disappeared, I heard a clapping sound clip and I entered a bonus challenge.

<s>The name may have either started with a Z, or contained repeated occurrences of the Z letter.</s>  Based on how I remember it looking, it probably targetted Windows 3.x, and I think I might have actually played it a couple of times under that OS; I have definitely not played it under anything later than Windows 98 SE.  It was already rather old by then.

Ring a bell?

Comment: I figured I might as well ask this game ID question while we still allow them…

Comment: Is there a motion to disallow game ID questions?

Comment: @WayneConrad More than one ([here's the most recent iirc](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1218/278)), but none of them have passed.

Comment: So why's this not vote to close when a similar question last week was ?

Comment: Close voters work in mysterious ways.

Comment: Have you checked the [Win 3.1 games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Windows_3.x_games) and searched for `Z`? There's a few suggestions there...

Comment: The use of the MK sample suggests it might have been a PD/shareware game, as mainstream publishers wouldn't have allowed it. The "Toasty" game mechanic was added to the MK series as from MK II so this puts your game as being released in 1994 at the earliest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the game you are looking for is some version of [Üz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqGPFWzVIVA). If you go to 4:25 and wait for a few seconds, you'll hear the "Toasty!" sound:

[image: Screenshot of Üz 3.0 in the middle of level 8, displaying the bonus round button]

I found this game on a compilation disk called "Millenium Gamepak," released in 1998 by BearWare.

Comment: Well done for the YouTube link, which should allow @user38470 to check whether the sound is as remembered.

Comment: Undoubtedly this. Almost everything (of what I could clearly recall) fits.

Comment: MobyGames has a listing for this game [here](https://www.mobygames.com/game/59970/uz-30/). I couldn't find any reference to any earlier versions of Üz than version 3.0, but it was shareware with a registered version available.

Comment: Outstanding. This q&a is a textbook case of how useful this type of question is to the asker and also the value of just leaving questions unanswered and open to be answered at a later date. I thank you on behalf of the asker, Brian

Answer (score -1):

I believe the game that you are talking about is called Zoombinis. Zoombinis was designed for educational purposes and was commonly used in schools to teach logic and problem-solving skills, so it may have been used in your computing class. It was compatible with various operating systems, including windows.

Comment: No, that doesn’t look like it at all. The game I remember had much simpler graphics than even the first game in this series, it had more fast-paced gameplay, and no human-like characters. And I doubt Zoombinis contains the mechanic with the “Toasty!” sound effect anywhere.